# Select and Checkbox components-> multiple options but with a maximum choice?

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui

I want to use the Select and Checkbox components with MUI with the multiple props , so the users can pick multiples options. However, I want , that they are limited to 3 options maximum . I can't find this props to set the min and maximum choice . Is it possible ?! I would be really happy if so .

Here is my code :

```
const languages = [
  "Anglais",
  "Arabe",
  "Espagnol",
  "Italien",
  "Français",
  "Mandarin",
  "Hebreu",
  "Russe",
  "Portugais",
  "Autre",
];

 <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
            <Select
              multiple={true}
              value={language}
              onChange={handleChange}
              MenuProps={MenuProps}
            >
              {languages.map((language) => (
                <MenuItem key={language} value={language}>
                  {language}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<Select
  multiple={true}
  value={language}
  onChange={handleChange}
  MenuProps={MenuProps}
>
  {languages.map((lang) => (
    <MenuItem
       key={lang}
       disabled={language.length >= 3 && !language.includes(lang)}
       value={lang}
    >
      {language}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</Select>
```

Had to change the `map` parameter since it's name is the same as the state variable.

This will disable any non-selected items when state (*language*) has 3 or more items.

Comment: Actually it was not working with your snippet , the select was empty  . So i changed the name of my state and the name of the array and it's finally work

Answer (score 1):

This should help you make it for yourself.

```js
const languages = [
  "Anglais",
  "Arabe",
  "Espagnol",
  "Italien",
  "Français",
  "Mandarin",
  "Hebreu",
  "Russe",
  "Portugais",
  "Autre",
];

const App = () => {
  const [selectedItem , setSelectedItem] = React.useState([]);
  const selectHandler = (e) => {
    const select = e.currentTarget.value;
    if(selectedItem.length <3)
      setSelectedItem((prev)=> [...prev,select])
  }
  return (
      <div>
        <p>{selectedItem.map((item)=>item+"-")}</p>
        <select onChange={selectHandler}>
          {languages.map((language) => (
            <option key={language} value={language}>
              {language}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>

  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

In your case, just pass `selectedItem` as a value to the Select component solve the problem.